# Error in getOptionChain expiry date for multiple tickers

Tags: r, finance, quantmod

I'm running the Getting options chain for multiple tickers but something is wrong with the expiration date for multiple tickers.

Here's a sample code:

```
library(quantmod)
Symbols <- c("XOM","MSFT","JNJ")
Options.20220429 <- getOptionChain("Symbols", "2022-04-29")
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> ```
>     Error in getOptionChain.yahoo(Symbols = "Symbols", Exp = "2022-04-29") : 
>   Provided expiry date(s) not found. Available dates are:
> ```

However, if I run a single ticker with same expiration date one by one like the one below, everything works fine.

```
getOptionChain("JNJ", "2022-04-29")
```

Comment: ```lapply(Symbols, getOptionChain, Exp = "2022-04-29")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the expiry date for each one of your tickers. The following code works:

```
Options.20220429 <- lapply(Symbols, getOptionChain, Exp = "2022-04-29")

names(Options.20220429) <- Symbols
```